# Flutter FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())

Tags: flutter, firebase

I used firebase in app but when I run the code with debugging ı I get this error FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())

my code is here

```
const String folderName = '/assets/DB/papers';
class PapersDataUploader extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onReady() {
    uploadData();
    super.onReady();
  }
  final loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.loading.obs;
  uploadData() async {
    loadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.loading;
    final fi = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    try {
      //read asset folder
      final manifestContent = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(Get.context!)
          .loadString('AssetManifest.json');
      final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
      //seperate quiz json files
      final papersInAsset = manifestMap.keys
          .where((path) =>
              path.startsWith('assets/DB/papers/') && path.contains('.json'))
          .toList();
      final List<QuizPaperModel> quizPapers = [];
      for (var paper in papersInAsset) {
        //read content of papers(json files)
        String stringPaperContent = await rootBundle.loadString(paper);
        //add data to model
        quizPapers.add(QuizPaperModel.fromString(stringPaperContent));
      }
      //upload data to firebase
      var batch = fi.batch();
      for (var paper in quizPapers) {
        batch.set(
          quizePaperFR.doc(paper.id),
          {
            "title": paper.title,
            "image_url": paper.imageUrl,
            "Description": paper.description,
            "time_seconds": paper.timeSeconds,
            "questions_count":
                paper.questions == null ? 0 : paper.questions!.length
          },
        );
        for (var questions in paper.questions!) {
          final questionPath =
              questionsFR(paperId: paper.id, questionsId: questions.id);

          batch.set(questionPath, {
            "question": questions.question,
            "correct_answer": questions.correctAnswer
          });

          for (var answer in questions.answers) {
            batch.set(questionPath.collection('answers').doc(answer.identifier),
                {"identifier": answer.identifier, "answer": answer.answer});
          }
        }
      }
      await batch.commit();
      loadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.completed;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      AppLogger.e(e);
    }
  }
}
```

final fi = FirebaseFirestore.instance;  this line getting error

`my main dart code is here`

```
Future<void> initFireBase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'quizApp',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initFireBase();
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    home: DataUploaderScreen(),
  ));
}
```

I initlizaling in main dart. how can ı fix this error.

Comment: I don't know Dart or Flutter, but might it be that you need to `return Firebase.initializeApp(....)` so that the main gets the value created by initilizeApp() rather than the value disappearing once the local scope of `initFireBase()` exits?

Answer (score 2):

From FlutterFire [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/):

> To create a new Firestore instance, call the instance getter on FirebaseFirestore:
>
> ```
> FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
> ```
>
> By default, this allows you to interact with Firestore using the
> default Firebase App used whilst installing FlutterFire on your
> platform. If however you'd like to use Firestore with a secondary
> Firebase App, use the instanceFor method:
>
> ```
> FirebaseApp secondaryApp = Firebase.app('SecondaryApp');
> FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp);
> ```

So I guess you should use `FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(Firebase.app('quizApp'))` instead of `FirebaseFirestore.instance`.

Alternatively, just initialise your FirebaseApp as default app:

```
Future<void> initFireBase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}
```